# Show milliseconds in Chronometer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I am making a stopwatch for android in eclipse. I am using chronometer and i want to know how do i show milliseconds.This is how my code looks like. P.S: I am a beginner, So this may sound stupid to you :P

```
       Button startChrono;
Button pauseChrono;
Chronometer chrono;
long time = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startChrono = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pauseChrono = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    startChrono.setOnClickListener(this);
    pauseChrono.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + time);
        chrono.start();
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        time = chrono.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        chrono.stop();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Chronometer.  It only supports fine-grained time resolution down to seconds.  Also, after looking at the code, I see they are doing this:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void More ...handleMessage(Message m) {
        if (mRunning) {
            updateText(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            dispatchChronometerTick();
            sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(this, TICK_WHAT), 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

Looks like it is intentional that it currently updates only once per second.  This is understandable as this component is a TextView and will typically cause a re-layout of its parent when the text changes (if layout_width is wrap_parent.)

You'll have to look for an alternate solution to get the level of detail and update performance you desire.